# SSH vs Wordpress

Tags: plugins, permissions, ssh

To modify files via SSH I need to have the files owned by ubuntu:www-data. But for wordpress to be able to install or update plugins I need to have the files owned by www-data:www-data. Any way around changing ownership all the time aside from manually adding the plugins? I have tried setting file/folder permissions to 664 and 775, 2664 and 2775, but it doesn't help. Not sure what the difference is between 644 and 664 or 775 and 755 if the users in the group aren't allowed to do stuff anyways.

Message received when trying to install a plugin via the front-end:
To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

Answer (score 1):

Checking what permissions you are actually setting is always a good idea before just doing so.

**644** = Owner Read/Write, Group Read, Others Read
**664** = Owner Read/Write, Group Read/Write, Others Read

**4** - Read, **2** - Write, **1** - Execute

You can see from sequence above 644 the first number 6 would be 4+2, Read+Write.  It's always **OWNER/GROUP/OTHERS**, so first number owner, second group, etc.

Set files to 664, and directories to 775.  I actually wrote a script a few years ago to do this automatically (you may need to change 644 to 664 and 755 to 775):
https://github.com/tripflex/scripts/blob/master/chmodwp

You would need to set write permissions for the group www-data which is why use 664 and 775.

Do you only get this issue when you do edit files via SSH?  There's a couple things you could do if the issue was the user/group, including using `runuser`

http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

Could just setup an alias for when you edit files, if that's what you're doing.

The problem you're having is because WordPress can't write to the files on your server.  Make sure your parent directory `www` or `public_html` is set to the right `user:group` and has the right permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The way I solved the issue was to install WP-CLI so I can install and update plugins via SSH. However, when I install or update plugins with WP-CLI the owner is ubuntu:ubuntu instead of ubuntu:www-data like all the other files. Is there a way to set the default group to www-data and default permissions to 664/775 instead of 644 and 755? I am not sure what issues this will cause with the group set to ubuntu instead of www-data, it seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Before messing with your server permissions, I would first try to use autoupdate via FTP.

Add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
/*
    See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Override_of_default_file_permissions for alternative methods.
*/
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct'); // try also 'ftpext' or 'ftpsockets'
define('FTP_USER', 'YOUR FTP LOGIN');
define('FTP_PASS', 'YOUR FTP PASSWORD');
define('FTP_HOST', 'YOUR FTP HOST (without http:// or ftp://)');
define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure what the difference is between 644 and 664 or 775 and 755 if
>   the users in the group aren't allowed to do stuff anyways.

You get three types of permissions: Read (r) value 4 - view the contents of the file, Write (w) value 2 - change the file content, Execute (x) value 1 - run the file as a program.

So for the first three of `rw-` it refers to the Owner.
You have - 6
That means you get three values that must add up to six 4 + 2 = 6, which means the Owner can view the contents and can write to the files and any other modification, so it looks like this `rw-`.

The group Owner is next in line and the Group Owner has read with 4 and read and write with 6.

Everyone else is represented by the last digit, in other words anyone who is not the owner or group owner.

So 4 means everyone else can only read the files as it should be.

So 644 = `rw-r--r--`
664 = `rw-rw-r--`

File permissions are extremely important on WordPress

The permission on files should be 664 = `rw-rw-r--` This is a permission on a VPS not a shared host.

Permission for files are 664 and directories are 775.
The owner is your user and the group owner is the web server `www-data`.

That is how you should be setting up your permissions on a VPS.

As far as the why, it has to do with the security principle called the Principle of Least Privilege, you can learn more about the why and the Principle of Least Privilege here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Answer (score -1):

You either want to be highly secure or not. If security is important to you, you just not going to let the web server write to anywhere except for the uploads directory which means that no automatic update (which IMO is a good think for other reasons as well). If you do want the functionality just set up an FTP server with a veru complex password.

Comment: Is this due to the ownership issue I mentioned or with mysql_secure_installation?

Comment: All default web server settings will not allow you to write to directories not set as 777 or similar, it is just considered to be insecure to do it any other way. In some practical situations you just don't have much choice, but if as it sounds you are running your own server, the extra security is worth the amount of extra time you will need to spend on manually updating themes/plugins/core files .